# Re-using the output of one cookbook in another cookbook

Tags: chef-infra

Consider I have 2 cookbooks, A and B and both are part of the runlist that is executed on AWS EC2 instance. First cookbook A executes some code and generates a value and stores it in node.run_state['pass'] variable. I need this value in cookbook B so is it possible that I can re-use this value in cookbook B directly since it is executed on the same node. I cannot test the scenario in kitchen because the cookbook A fails in kitchen because of some dependencies. I need to try this in EC2 directly but need to get understanding before I try it. Newbie to Chef, please help understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can read and write the node attributes and run_state from different cookbooks and there for share some information between them. But you need to keep in mind that:

1. Cookbook A must be run before cookbook B either in run list, or cookbook B must have `include_recipe 'A'` in its recipe.
2. There are 2 phases in Chef run: compile and execute. First the compile stage is executed in both cookbooks and then comes execution stage. So you must make sure you actually write the run_state variable in A before reading it in B.

Comment: Thanks Draco. On the 2nd point you mentioned, how can I ensure the variable actually has value before its being read in the 2nd cookbook ? Does the include_recipe 'A' already handle that ? Is there a way I tell to read the var only once its populated by 'A'

Comment: It depends on your recipes, there is no universal solution.

Comment: You can match `.nil?` for your `node.run_state` attribute and take appropriate action. E.g. `node.run_state['my_attribute'].nil?`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it can be helpful debugging these situations by viewing the output of the node.run_state attribute from recipe 'A' that you are attempting to read into recipe 'B' both with and without the lazy modifier.

```
log 'foo' do
  message "node.run_state['foo']: #{node.run_state['foo']}"
  level :info
end
```

```
log 'lazy foo' do
  message lazy "{ node.run_state['foo']: #{node.run_state['foo']} }"
  level :info
end
```